# Floatrow different margin caption justification based on even-odd page

Tags: captions, double-sided, floatrow, changepage

I want caption justification to behave differently for even and odd pages in a twoside document.

Consider the following MWE where I use packages **caption** and **floatrow** to achieve figure captions in the page margin.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\floatsetup{margins=hangoutside,capposition=beside,
capbesideposition={top,outside},floatwidth=\textwidth,facing=yes}

\newcommand\rightlast{\leftskip0ptplus1fil
\rightskip0ptplus-1fil\parfillskip0ptplus1fil}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{rightlast}{\rightlast}

\ifoddpage
\captionsetup[capbesidefigure]{labelsep=newline,labelfont=bf,justification=justified}
\else
\captionsetup[capbesidefigure]{labelsep=newline,labelfont=bf,justification=rightlast}
\fi

\begin{document}
\
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{test1}
\includegraphics[]{demo}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{test2}
\includegraphics[]{demo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The normal behaviour is **justified** so from the floatrow manual I used the newcommand **rightlast** to make the even(left) margin caption be next to the body text.

By using the **changepage** package I tried to check if a page is odd and use **justified** or even and use **rightlast** but it is not working like I expected.

I now get this:
[image]

What I want is this:
[image]

Comment: First of all, you need \checkoddpage and \ifoddpage in each float (especially if they actually float to a new page).  OTOH, placing \captionsetup inside the float seems to have no effect (as opposed to the preamble).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the odd page check to inside `\rightlast`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\floatsetup{margins=hangoutside,capposition=beside,
capbesideposition={top,outside},floatwidth=\textwidth,facing=yes}

\newcommand\rightlast{\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage\else
  \leftskip0ptplus1fil
  \rightskip0ptplus-1fil\parfillskip0ptplus1fil
\fi}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{rightlast}{\rightlast}

\captionsetup[capbesidefigure]{labelsep=newline,labelfont=bf,justification=rightlast}

\begin{document}
\
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{test1}
\includegraphics[]{demo}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{test2}
\includegraphics[]{demo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Simple yet so hard to think of sometimes!